# Set Null if no Results Returned EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I get a Word from the database and printout its "Text" using ViewBag in my ASP.NET MVC3 EntityFramework project.

```
ViewBag.ManagementSystems = db.Words.Where(w => w.WordBaseID == 1 && w.LanguageID == lang).FirstOrDefault().Text;
```

However, if no results are returned, I got null exception and program crashes. What is the simplest and best way of printing nothing if no results are returned?

Solutions I know of:

1- Surround with if's or try-catch blocks

2- Use

```
var query = "SELECT Text FROM Words WHERE WordBaseID = {0} AND LanguageID = {1}";
ViewBag.ManagementSystems= db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query, 1, lang).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Can't you check if it is null using if...else?

Comment: I already told I'm aware of it, I asked what is the best and the most "handsome" solution for this.

Comment: ok..i thought you will point out the reason why you dont want to use if...else.Any special reason for it?

Comment: No, I just want the code look good and well-structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose:

```
ViewBag.ManagementSystems = db.Words.Where(w => w.WordBaseID == 1 && w.LanguageID == lang)
                                    .Select(x => x.Text).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That's absolutely what I'm looking for. Thanks.